# Debian 9 - включение через /dev/loop образа в RAID - получаю ошибку занятости!

Tags: linux, debian, raid

Сразу оговорюсь, в предыдущих дистрибутивах **Weezy** и **Jessie** - все прекрасно работало..!
Теперь в чем проблема:
Есть образ, который необходимо внести в **RAID** массив, зачем, это уже другой вопрос - надо!
что я делаю:

> *# losetup /dev/loop10 /home/img/disk0.img*
>   получаем:
>   *# losetup -a*
>  
>           /dev/loop10: [2054]:11403305 (/home/img/disk0.img)

следующий этап, создаем RAID массив:

> *# mdadm --create /dev/md3 --auto=yes --level=1 --raid-devices=2 missing* /dev/loop10
>   получаю это:
>   *# mdadm: cannot open /dev/loop10: Device or resource busy*

смотрим кто "виноват":

> *# lsof|grep loop10*
>
> > loop10    10610             root  cwd       DIR                8,1     4096          2 /
> >     loop10    10610             root  rtd       DIR                8,1      4096          2 /
> >     loop10    10610             root  txt   unknown                                         /proc/10610/exe

дополнительно:

> *#cat /proc/mdstat*
>
> > `Personalities : [linear] [multipath] [raid0] [raid1] [raid6] [raid5] [raid4] [raid10]`
> >     `md3 : inactive loop10[1](S)`
> >     `1047552 blocks super 1.2`
> >     `unused devices: <none>`

*.. что это?

.. и как сделать что бы этого не происходило?*

Comment: ps aux | grep 10610 покажите

Comment: перецепил сейчас снова:   lsof|grep loop10
loop10    14342             root  cwd       DIR                8,1      4096          2 /
loop10    14342             root  rtd       DIR                8,1      4096          2 /
loop10    14342             root  txt   unknown

Comment: ps aux | grep 14343

Comment: root     14398  0.0  0.0  12784   972 pts/1    S+   22:38   0:00 grep 14343

Comment: тоесть процесс как бы есть, но в ps его нет.. странно!

Comment: root      2634  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   23:06   0:00 [loop1]
у меня видно

Comment: на арче создалось. на девятке завтра пробую отладить это...

Comment: Интересно, откуда взялся md30, может его удалить ?

Comment: исправил пример.. просто я создавал /dev/md30.

Comment: еще раз повторил всю процедуру(уже наверно раз 50..)

Comment: losetup /dev/loop10 disk0.img

Comment: mdadm --create /dev/md10 --auto=yes --level=1 --raid-devices=2 missing /dev/loop10

Comment: mdadm: cannot open /dev/loop10: Device or resource busy

Comment: ps aux | grep 8295

Comment: root      8295  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   23:27   0:00 [loop10]

Comment: root      8347  0.0  0.0  12784   944 pts/1    S+   23:27   0:00 grep 8295

Comment: что обозначает это: root 8295 0.0 0.0 0 0 ? S< 23:27 0:00 [loop10]

Comment: так это модуль ядра который связывает луп на файл.

Comment: Посмотри  `file  /home/img/disk0.img` и можно ещё глянуть `dmesg` после поднятия петли

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У меня все работает:

```
root@srv1:/target# file /backup/windows-2003-S
/backup/windows-2003-S: DOS/MBR boot sector; partition 1 : ID=0x7, start-CHS (0x0,1,1), end-CHS (0x3ff,254,63), startsector 63, 58717512 sectors, extended partition table (last)

root@srv1:/target# losetup /dev/loop10 /backup/windows-2003-S 
root@srv1:/target# losetup -a
/dev/loop1: [2049]:63 (/backup/windows-2003-S.part)
/dev/loop0: [2049]:62 (/backup/windows-2003-S)
/dev/loop10: [2049]:62 (/backup/windows-2003-S)

root@srv1:/target# mdadm --create /dev/md3 --auto=yes --level=1 --raid-devices=2 missing /dev/loop10
mdadm: /dev/loop10 appears to be part of a raid array:
       level=raid0 devices=0 ctime=Thu Jan  1 03:00:00 1970
mdadm: partition table exists on /dev/loop10 but will be lost or
       meaningless after creating array
mdadm: Note: this array has metadata at the start and
    may not be suitable as a boot device.  If you plan to
    store '/boot' on this device please ensure that
    your boot-loader understands md/v1.x metadata, or use
    --metadata=0.90
Continue creating array? y
mdadm: Defaulting to version 1.2 metadata
mdadm: array /dev/md3 started.

root@srv1:/target# cat /etc/*rele*
PRETTY_NAME="Debian GNU/Linux 9 (stretch)"
NAME="Debian GNU/Linux"
VERSION_ID="9"
VERSION="9 (stretch)"


root@srv1:/target# aptitude show linux-image-amd64
Пакет: linux-image-amd64                         
Версия: 4.9+80+deb9u1
```

Comment: :-) я таки нашел в чем проблема, точнее это не проблема а новый алгоритм работы mdadm в stratch. а теперь по порядку...

Comment: При первом подключении устройства /dev/loop в массив - да все пройдет успешно, но при повторном подключении вы получите сообщение об ошибки если делать команду создания массива так же как и в первый раз: mdadm --create /dev/md10 --auto=yes --level=1 --raid-devices=2 missing /dev/loop10

Comment: но если перед этим (внимание возможна потеря данных) сделать к /dev/loop10: mdadm --zero-superblock /dev/loop10, то все пройдет успешно, только вот информации там уже скорее всего не будет... Правильно при повторном включении RAID: echo -e "y"|sudo mdadm --run /dev/loop10

Comment: почему так? mdadm когда вы просите его восстановить ваш /dev/md* - то он сканирует устройства и ищет там информацию об /dev/md*

Comment: в предыдущих версиях mdadm такого я не видел, поэтому и "прокатывало"... в новой версии похоже все сильно переписали.. такие дела. Всем спасибо за посильную помощь!

Comment: у меня была догадка что раидовский суперблок есть в образе... потому и спросил про дмесг

Comment: dmesg -  к сожалению тут говорит, что все ок...

Comment: а где нашли? интеренсно

Comment: ...была как то проблема, несколько аналогичная..(http://support.qbpro.ru/index.php?title=%D0%92%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85_%D0%BD%D0%B0_RAID_%D0%B2_%D1%81%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%B5_%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F_suberblock) скажем так, дошел до решения сам. Необходимо доделать работу, поэтому у меня нет выбора, нужно решать любым способом.